# Add class to template based on boolean field

Tags: 7, theming, display-suite

I want to add a class to my custom Display Suite template if a boolean field is checked on the form. I have the following code:

```
if (isset($node->field_boolean_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) == 1 ) :
    $class = 'this-is-the-class';
endif;
```

And then in the appropriate place:

```
<a href="#" class="<?php print $class ?>">link</a>
```

This always returns the class regardless of whether the boolean field is checked or not though.

```
<a href="#" class="this-is-the-class">link</a>
```

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written wrong logic in if statement. Correct way is following:

```
 $class = NULL;
 if (isset($node->field_boolean_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) && $node->field_boolean_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 1 ) :
        $class = 'this-is-the-class';
 endif;
```

Comment: Thanks Rupesh, I see now that the query needs to be there once for the `if` statement and once for `isset`, otherwise the `if` has no query attached to it.